# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor afterExecute's runnable.toString is different

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable, java-threads

I am relatively new to `ThreadPoolExecutor`. I'm seeing if I can track the runnable before being **executed** and in **afterExecute**.

By getting `runnable.toString()` using `afterExecute(Runnable t, Throwable t)`. Now, I realize I could just put a Log inside the runnable itself... but I was curious what this method would produce.

For `ThreadPoolExecutor`, works fine, `runnable.toString` is the same before `execute(runnable)` and also in `afterExecute()`.

However! `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` is different. Its **afterExecute's runnable.toString is quite different**.

For example, before: `my.pkg.name@abc`, afterExecute: `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@zxc`

Not even the pkg name is the same.
Why is this?

```
private MyThreadPool() {
    threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(NUMBER_OF_CORES, MAX_CORES,
        KEEP_ALIVE_TIME, KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_UNIT, workQueue) {
        @Override
        public void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
            super.afterExecute(r, t);
            Log.d(TAG, "ThreadOps onDone: " + r.toString());
            // (A) will return same --> mypkgname@abc
        }
    };
    threadPool.setRejectedExecutionHandler(rejectedHandler);

    scheduledThreadPool = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(NUMBER_OF_CORES) {
        @Override
        public void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
            super.afterExecute(r, t);
            Log.d(TAG, "ThreadOps onDelayDone: " + r.toString());
            // (D) does not return same?
            // I am expecting --> mypkgname@qwe , but get...
            // java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@zxc
        }
    };
    scheduledThreadPool.setRejectedExecutionHandler(rejectedHandler);
}

public void execute(Runnable runnable) {
    Log.d(TAG, "ThreadOps exe: " + runnable.toString());
    // (A) lets say toString --> mypkgname@abc
    threadPool.execute(runnable);
}

public void delayExecute(Runnable runnable, long delayms) {
    Log.d(TAG, "ThreadOps exe @" + delayms + ": " + runnable.toString());
    // (D) lets say toString --> mypkgname@qwe
    scheduledThreadPool.schedule(runnable, delayms, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` internally maintains a heap of sorts to easily add and retrieve submitted tasks based on their scheduled (ie. the one that needs to be executed next at the top of the heap).

To help accessing this heap, the implementation of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` decorates the `Runnable` or `Callable` instances you `schedule` with a custom implementation that describes its position in the heap, among other things. That's the `ScheduledFutureTask` you see in your logs. Note that this is an implementation detail (it's a `private` class) and you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Thank you. I see, so it gets transformed in another class, then execute'd from there, that explains why the toString has completely changed.